# Which free text analysis tools do authors use?

Tags: software, tools, text-analysis

I'm looking for free tools to perform some text analysis.  I don't want just simple Flesch-Kinvaid or Coleman-Liau score, I was hoping for a tool that identifies problem sentences, overused words, etc.

There is a plugin for Google Docs called "ProWritingAid", but every report requires payment.  Before I go ahead and pay for it, I wanted to check in and see if there were standard free tools available for creative writers.

Comment: Just found another one:  Grammarly.  Like ProWritingAid it looks free to start but costs money for the more serious analysis.

Comment: Not free, but great, AutoCrit is another option. It costs a monthly fee, but the cost is worth it. I use it and love it. It is a website and you just put your work in it. Note: it is entirely focused on style not grammar.

Comment: I use Grammarly. The free plan does all the basic things like correct grammar, punctuation etc. If you buy the pro plan, it does extra work like better words to use. It works really well.

Comment: I've always relied on my own reading of my work, and my readers'. I never knew there was software to do this.

Answer (score 5):

The [Hemingway](http://www.hemingwayapp.com/) "app" (a website, really) is probably the most common suggestion for this, although you can Google others to try. You may need to experiment with a few of them. Unfortunately, the Hemingway app [can condemn Hemingway's writing](https://whyevolutionistrue.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/hemingway-app-judges-writing-badly/).

Answer (score 2):

Grammarly.

It does the job, essentially everything you've said and it's definitely worth your money.

Comment: The question asks about free tools and your answer says this one is worth the money.  Does it have a free version?  Could you [edit] in more information?

Comment: Yeah, there is a free version. But the pro version (cost money) gives more features.

Answer (score 1):

*Sorted from most technical to least technical.*

My first thought was to use Python with the [NLTK package](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html).

If that's too technical the somewhat less technical [AllenNLP](http://allennlp.org) might be worth to check out. It supports [co-reference resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreference#Coreference_resolution), which means it can track entities across sentences. It could be useful for checking whether you're overusing words.

Did a quick Github search for `correct sentence` and found:

- [chat correct](https://github.com/diasks2/chat_correct): a Ruby script that helps correcting sentences and that shows the mistake made.
- [Markov sentence correction](https://github.com/anassinator/markov-sentence-correction): a Python script using a Hidden Markov model (i.e. machine learning) to correct sentences based on a vocabulary list.

Did an other Github search on `grammar check`:

- [language-check](https://github.com/myint/language-check): a Python script using [LanguageTool](https://www.languagetool.org) that checks for writing mistakes and can automatically give a suggestion for improvement.

[LanguageTool](https://www.languagetool.org): provides a simple browser add-on for FireFox and Chrome. It also has a stand-alone version and a Google Docs add-on. I think this would be the least technical solution.